# VBA How to check if an Array contains a string in a Range

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

I'm trying to write a little loop to check if a selected range contains any of the values in the Array.

```vb
Sub test()
    Dim DirArray As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    'define array
    DirArray = Sheets("Blad1").Range("A1:A311").Value

    'Loop trough array
    For i = 1 To UBound(DirArray)
        'Activate the sheet with the Range
        Sheets("Blad1").Activate

        'Go through range of values
        If DirArray = Cells(i, 2) Then
            MsgBox "it contains the value"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

I think I'm making the error by using `Cells(i,2)`, it says the Types don't match. I've been looking at it for so long I think I'm missing something obvious.

Any help or feedback would be appreciated!

Comment: You cannot compare an array to anything. Use two nested loops.

Comment: You have to specify the specific element of the array in the loop, but use MATCH to obviate need for a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Integer, z, DirArray As Variant
    With Sheets("Blad1")
        'Define array
        DirArray = .Range("A1:A311").Value
        'Loop trough array
        For i = 1 To UBound(DirArray)
            '// Use Excel's Match function:
            '// if the value of 'z' is not Error, then match is found.
            '// Note that if you use WorksheetFunction.Match instead of
            '// Application.Match and the value won't be found, then
            '// error will be raised, in which case you need to use error handler.
            '// To avoid this ceremony, use Application.Match since it won't raise
            '// error, but the value of 'z' will just contain Error.
            z = Application.Match(.Cells(i, 2), DirArray, 0)
            If Not IsError(z) Then
                MsgBox "it contains the value"
            End If
        Next i
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This can be done without any loop at all, if OP just wants to know if any value in `DirArray` does exist in their B column equivalent. Either way. In your case you could also do: `If Application.Count(Application.Match(.Cells(i,2), DirArray, 0)) > 0 Then MsgBox "it contains the value"`. This would remove the need for an extra `IsError` check. +1

Comment: @JvdV I guess OP needs to check all values in column `B` against array values.

Comment: Yes, I meant that can be done too, without any loop, as long OP is just interested in the fact if any is present.

Comment: @JvdV You still have two loops, one visible, where you loop the `i`, and one hidden that is inside `Application.Match`. You can't call `Application.Count(Application.Match())` either as `Application.Match` returns a single number.

Comment: @GSerg, `Application.Match` can return an array of results. I've put down an answer below to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 1):

Just for demonstration practices, I wanted to show you wouldn't need any (visible) loop to compare two 1D-arrays to return if ***any*** of the elements in one array is found in the other array.

To do so we can use the following code:

```
Sub Test()

Dim arr1 As Variant: arr1 = Array("A", "B", "C", "D")
Dim arr2 As Variant: arr2 = Array("D", "E", "B")

With Application
    If .Count(.Match(arr2, arr1, 0)) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "It contains values from arr1"
    Else
        MsgBox "It does not contain values from arr1"
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

---

What does this actually do? `Application.Match` is able to compare two arrays, so in this case effectively you could think of:

```
.Match({"D", "E", "B"}, {"A", "B", "C", "D"}, 0)
```

It will compare each element in the first array against all elements in the second array, and most importantly it will return an array on it's own with the results:

```
Results = {4, Error 2042, 2}
```

As @JohnyL also explained, using `Application.Match` will not raise an run-time error when values are not found, it will continue and will put non-found matches in the array itself, showing an error in the results instead.

Now to check if there are any result we would need `Application.Count` to return the number of numeric values withing the resulting array.

```
.Count({4, Error 2042, 2})
```

In this case the result will be `2`, telling us (higher than zero) that there are two values that have got a match.

---

***<sub>How would this help OP?</sub>***

In his case we would need one more function to return two 1D-arrays directly from the `Range` objects. Op seems to compare `Range("A1:A311")` against `Range("B1:B311")` so we could try the below:

```
Sub Test2()

Dim arr1 As Variant: arr1 = Sheets("Blad1").Range("A1:B311").Value

With Application
    If .Count(.Match(.Index(arr1, 0, 1), .Index(arr1, 0, 2), 0)) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "It contains values from arr1"
    Else
        MsgBox "It does not contain values from arr1"
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

The only extra method I used was `Application.Index` to slice two 1D-arrays directly from the full 2D-array.

Another technique would be to use `Application.Transpose` if both A and B column would be of different size. You would pull them into a seperate variant variable and `Transpose` them once into a 1D-array.

Comment: Fine demonstration of not so well known possibilities of the `Application.Match()` function :+)